# How to compare a piece of one cell to multiple cells for duplicates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to find duplicates by comparing the contents of a cell with multiple cells. For example:

I want to compare the contents of B2 to the cells in column A. I want to highlight the matches in B2.

[image: img]

The red text would be the matches. Is this possible? All I know of is the IF(COUNTIF) but I haven't been able to get that to work for pieces of a cell.

Thanks

Comment: You could to Text to Columns on `B1`, using a semicolon delimiter, then do your `COUNTIF()` under it.  Granted it won't be in a single cell, but that would work. Alternatively, just do text-to-columns then throw a conditional format on the results with `COUNTIF()`.

Comment: A single cell cannot have two different formats.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 What do you mean by that?  Clearly, in the OP's screenshot, the phrases in `B2` have more than one font color.

Comment: In order to highlight (turn font color red), for only some of the phrases in `B2`, you will need to use a VBA solution.  Also, the contents of `B2` must be a text string; it cannot be the result of a formula in that cell.